# Is the group of conformal automorphisms of a (complete) finite volume hyperbolic manifold finite?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let $ M $ be a Riemannian manifold. Let $ Iso(M) $ be the group of isometries of $ M $.
Let $ Conf(M) $ be the conformal group of $ M $ (the group of all diffeomorphisms of $ M $ that preserve the conformal structure induced by the metric).

A hyperbolic manifold is a manifold equipped with a metric of constant negative sectional curvature.

It is well known that a (complete) hyperbolic manifold with finite volume must have finite $ Iso(M) $.

What about $ Conf(M) $? That is, must $ Conf(M) $ be finite for a complete hyperbolic manifold of finite volume?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the uniformization theorem. An exercise (using Liouville's theorem) is to show that the group of (anti)conformal automorphisms of the unit ball equals its group of Moebius automorphisms, equals the group of hyperbolic isometries.

Comment: Ok I'll take out the reference to uniformization

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah I see so that the conformal group is equal to the isometry for any hyperbolic manifold follows from Liouville's theorem basically as described here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160459/conformal-automorphism-of-hn?noredirect=1&lq=1 . Are there any other types of locally symmetric spaces for which the conformal group is always equal to the isometry group?

Comment: Probably always except for sphere and Euclidean space (apply Ferrand's theorem).

Comment: @MoisheKohan that sounds great! What is Ferrand's theorem and where do I find it? So is the round sphere a case where there are non-isometric conformal automorphisms?

Comment: "The action of conformal transformations on a Riemannian manifold." Math. Ann.304(1996), no.2, 277–291. But it is just a suggestion how to proceed: I do not have a complete argument.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836697/is-the-isometry-group-of-a-finite-volume-negatively-curved-manifold-finite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Let $ (M,g) $ be a finite volume hyperbolic manifold. Let $ \mathrm{Conf}(M,g) $ be the conformal group. Since $ M $ is a finite volume hyperbolic manifold (it must have dimension strictly greater than $ 1 $ and)  it cannot be conformally equivalent to $ E^n $ or $ S^n $. So we can apply a theorem of Ferrand https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01446294
to conclude that there exits some other metric $ g' $ which is conformally equivalent $ g \sim g' $ and such that $ \mathrm{Conf}(M,g)=\mathrm{Iso}(M,g') $. Since $ g' $ is conformally equivalent to the finite volume hyperbolic metric $ g $ then $ (M,g') $ is also a finite volume hyperbolic manifold. But a finite volume hyperbolic manifold must have finite isometry group. Thus $ \mathrm{Iso}(M,g')=\mathrm{Conf}(M,g) $ must be finite.</strike>

Although perhaps that argument is missing that point and all that really needs to be said is (according to Mike Miller Eismeier): if $ f:M \to M $
is a conformal automorphism, the lift to the universal cover is a conformal automorphism of $ \mathbb{H}^n $, hence an isometry, and the behavior on tangent spaces is the same upstairs and downstairs, so $f$
is an isometry to begin with. This shows $ \mathrm{Conf}(M)=\mathrm{Iso}(M) $ and then we use that a complete finite volume negatively curved manifold has finite isometry group [Why is the isometry group of a closed negatively curved manifold finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220082/why-is-the-isometry-group-of-a-closed-negatively-curved-manifold-finite)

Comment: The argument in the 1st paragraph is wrong, the mistake is in the sentence "Since ′ is conformally equivalent to the finite volume hyperbolic metric  then (,′) is also a finite volume hyperbolic manifold." The argument in the 2nd paragraph is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks I did strike through on the incorrect argument

Comment: @MoisheKohan You said that the argument in my 2nd paragraph is correct but the last part of the argument claims that "a finite volume negatively curved manifold has finite isometry group" at least this part seem to be false according to the answer given here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4836715/758507 is the overall argument salvageable?

Comment: One usually assumes completeness of the metric.

Comment: Oh great that just I was looking for, I've edited "complete" into the question and answer in appropriate places