# Is the isometry group of a finite volume negatively curved manifold finite?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

Is the isometry group of a finite volume negatively curved manifold finite?

If $ M $ is compact then this is true see [Why is the isometry group of a closed negatively curved manifold finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220082/why-is-the-isometry-group-of-a-closed-negatively-curved-manifold-finite)

But what if $ M $ is finite volume noncompact? Then does negative curvature still imply finite isometry group?

Comment: You have to assume that the manifold is complete.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836752/why-is-the-isometry-group-of-a-complete-finite-volume-negatively-curved-manifold

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The isometry group of a finite volume negatively curved manifold need not be finite.

Consider $B_\epsilon(0)\subset \mathbb{H}^2$ in the Poincare disk model for $0<\epsilon<1$. Since this ball is precompact, with closure contained inside of $\mathbb{H}^2$, $\mathrm{Vol}(B_{\epsilon}(0))<\infty$. However, the rotations about the origin are hyperbolic isometries and hence form a one parameter (and hence infinite) family of isometries.