# Conformal group of the Weeks manifold

Tags: geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry, isometry

The Weeks manifold https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weeks_manifold is an arithmetic hyperbolic 3-manifold known for having the smallest volume of any closed orientable hyperbolic 3-manifold (if you remove the word orientable this is false since the Weeks manifold is the orientable double cover of a non-orientable hyperbolic 3-manifold of exactly half the volume).

The isometry group of the Weeks manifold is $ D_6 $, the dihedral group of order $ 12 $, [see first row of table 1 in Hodgson and Weeks](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1048515809).

This is consistent with the fact that the isometry group of a closed hyperbolic 3 manifold is always finite (in fact this even true for finite volume hyperbolic 3-manifolds). Indeed, every finite group is the isometry group of some closed hyperbolic 3-manifold.

What is the conformal group of the Weeks manifold? Is it $ D_6 $? Is it at least finite? If the conformal group is not $ D_6 $ then what is an example of a conformal automorphism of the Weeks manifold that is not an isometry?

Comment: It looks like [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160459/conformal-automorphism-of-hn) may answer your question?

Comment: @LeeMosher ah you're right, do you want to just post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any complete hyperbolic $n$-manifold $M$, its self-isometry group is equal to its self-conformal group.

In dimensions $n \ge 3$ this is a very quick consequence of [Liouville's Theorem for conformal maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160459/conformal-automorphism-of-hn) which has the corollary that the conformal self-maps of $\mathbb H^n$ are precisely the isometries of $\mathbb H^n$.

To fill in the "very quick" argument, let $p : \mathbb H^n \to M$ be any locally isometric universal covering map, and consider any self-conformal map $f : M \to M$. Let $F : \mathbb H^n \to \mathbb H^n$ be any lift of $f$, and so we have the commutativity relation $p \circ F = f \circ p$. Also $F$ is conformal, and it follows from Liouville's Theorem that $F$ is an isometry of $\mathbb H^n$. Together with the commutativity relation and the fact that $p$ is a local isometry, it follows that $f$ is an isometry of $M$.